# Blazkowicz's quote after defeating the planes in Wolfenstein: The New Order

Tags: wolfenstein-the-new-order

Who exactly is B.J. referring to by 'you' in this quote?

> "Death at the gates again. Howling my name. Can't greet you today. I have a war to win.",

Source: [Fandom Wiki](https://wolfenstein.fandom.com/wiki/William_J._Blazkowicz/Quotes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "you" in this quote refers to death, itself.

In B.J.s eyes, death is coming back for him. Hell..  B.J. has already cheated death on more than one occasion.

B.J. doesn't have time to die. He has to defeat the Nazis.

Comment: ohh now it makes sense